# React hooks. How to pass args from one element to other

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

Salute. I'am moving simple todoApp from Components to Hooks. So here is the question: I am creating a deleter from an array of todos in my App.js(highest one) file and pass it to another component.

So here it is:

```
const App = () => {
  const [todoData, onDeleted] = useState([
    { label: "Drink Coffee", important: false, id: 1 },
    { label: "Make Awesome App", important: true, id: 2 },
    { label: "Have a lunch", important: false, id: 3 }
  ]);

  const deleteHandler = id => {
    todoData.filter(obj => obj.id !== id);
  };
  return(
      <TodoList todos={todoData} onDeleted={onDeleted(id => deleteHandler(id)))} />
)
```

In todo-list.js i do this.

```
      <li key={id} className="list-group-item">
        <TodoListItem {...itemProps} onDeleted={() => onDeleted()} />
      </li>
```

In todo-list-item.js i do this:

```
<button
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm float-right"
        onClick={onDeleted}
      >
```

So... I don't really how to properly pass an id of an element to delete handler, also I get 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined'. What am I doing wrong and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve deletion would be to do something like this:

```js
const App = () => {
  // Renamed onDeleted to setTodoData, to keep code cleaner.
  const [todoData, setTodoData] = useState([
    { label: "Drink Coffee", important: false, id: 1 },
    { label: "Make Awesome App", important: true, id: 2 },
    { label: "Have a lunch", important: false, id: 3 }
  ]);

  const onDeleted = id => {
    setTodoData(todoData => todoData.filter(obj => obj.id !== id));
  };

  // Avoid passing anonymous functions as props, it may trigger re-renders and worsen performance.
  return (
      <TodoList todos={todoData} onDeleted={onDeleted} />
  );
}
```

```js
// Make sure to pass id here, I assume it's in itemProps, replaced the anonymous function with some prop drilling.
<li key={id} className="list-group-item">
  <TodoListItem {...itemProps} onDeleted={onDeleted} />
</li>
```

And now for the button part (assuming id exists on props):

```js
const deleteItem = () => {
  props.onDeleted(props.id);
};
```

```js
<button
  type="button"
  className="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm float-right"
  onClick={deleteItem}
>
```

Generally to avoid the problem of prop drilling (passing down the same prop through multiple components) I would suggest to use Redux (with its great hooks like useSelector and useDispatch). Also, avoid passing anonymous functions to component properties.

Comment: So much love to you